# CSRF tokens for browser and non browser clients

Tags: security, csrf, csrf-protection

We can implement token prevention for CSRF fine - by, for example, a hidden field in the browser that is sent on javascript web service / REST requests from the page and checked on the server against a token in a cookie.

This can be done fairly painlessly accross our internal and external web applications using some standard server code, javascript etc.

This would seem to work fine and make sense as the token on the page is validating the origin of the request.

All good.

The problem is we also use the same REST / SOAP endpoints from non broswer clients i.e. other services within the enteprise network.

These clients are not vulnerable to CSRF because they don't execute javascript.

However, short of some form of IP whitelisting - which in an enteprise environment can be very problematic - CSRD tokens break non browser clients.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to have JS enabled in order to have CSRF vulnerabilities. if you have an URL such as

```
http://example.com/site?logout=1
```

which logs you out, this URL can be played by the user out of the normal scope of activities. JS is just one of the enablers.

This said, your CSRF tokens should go into standard HTTP headers and these are not likely to break anything (except if your clients are very peculiar and rely on exact headers to work)

Comment: Some clients are other applications - not browsers- so they do not get the token in  the way a browser would.  They don't have the token to set in the header.  They just post to //server/dosomework passing some credentials in a cookie or automatically obtained by broser.   The same service is used by the browser.  So the services are potentially vulnerably - because of the cookie/token - which can be fixed using CSRF tokens sent from the server to the browser and then sent in standard headers - but the none browser clients dont have the token - because they haven't browsed to the site!

Comment: @stuartm9999: API endpoints are normally not vulnerable to CSRF as the calls are independent and authentication is provided with each call and you do not have JS as a useful enabler for the attacks. You would need to have the user click on a link like the one I mentioned in my answer..

Comment: *"API endpoints are normally not vulnerable to CSRF* -  the same API is being used by browsers too so they are.

Answer (score 0):

OK - we solved this by issuing / checking for headers that cannot be manipulated.
https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-header-name
So - either check for the presense of one of these or add your own header begining with Sec- e.g. Sec-IsBrowser then do the following logic

```
    IF(ForbiddenHeader is present and not null and not empty string/or check for a few)
    {
        OWASP at this point recommends if the ORIGIN is present then check its OK  -
    OR if the Referer is present check if OK (OK meaning an expected value e.g. www.mysite)
Reject - if either of these tests fail
(OWASP says if you cant find either of these headers - choose to reject or proceed)
Then Check your CORS token
}
ELSE
{
Hopefully the caller was not a browser so were OK as nothing is there to automatically post our authentication token
}
```